# Google Visualization, can you assign the color of the slice based on a column's value?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying the following to assign a color based on the value, but this is not working, it is just assigning the default values. This methods works with other chart types. Bear in mind I cannot use color in the options because the rows can come in different order. Any ideas?

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();        
  data.addColumn('string', 'Status');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Count');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
  data.addRow(['Failure', 8,'color:#EE4A49']);
  data.addRow(['Warning', 1,'color:#E3d157']);
  data.addRow(['Success', 1,'color:#45B7AF']);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zYS27/15/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based [on the current API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart) I think you may need to preprocess the data before passing it to Google Charts.

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();        
  data.addColumn('string', 'Status');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Count');
  data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'style'});
  data.addRow(['Failure', 8,'color:#EE4A49']);
  data.addRow(['Warning', 1,'color:#E3d157']);
  data.addRow(['Success', 1,'color:#45B7AF']);

var myColors = { 'Failure' : 'red', 'Success': 'green', 'Warning': 'yellow' };

var slicesColor = {};

for( var i=0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++){
  // I assume the label is in the first column of each row here
  // this is based on string matching, but you can define any criteria you want
  slicesColor[i] = {color: myColors[data.getValue(i, 0)] };
}

var options = {
  ...
  slices: slicesColor
}

var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
  chart.draw(data, option);   
}
...
```

Comment: so, moral of the story is you can't use style in the addColumn for pies?